# SSIS Package Inoperable After Upgrade of Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

I am having an issue with one of my SSIS projects. I developed this package over a year ago and it has run flawlessly until I upgraded Visual Studio. The original project was in VS Shell 2010. My new version is VS 2017 Pro.

The setup is pretty basic. I am pulling data from a database file (.db) using an ADO.NET source via SQLite3 ODBC driver. It pulls each table and inserts the data into a MS SQL Server table. The Target Server Version is set to SQL Server 2012. It is encrypted with password. When I say I have tried to execute the package, I'm talking within VS.

Here is the issue:
Upon executing, the package will execute the SQL statements that start the processes, when I get to the first data flow that has a pull from the database, a command window flashed briefly and closes. The package completes in error:

```
[Assignments [290]] Error: The Assignments was unable to process the data. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
[Resources [801]] Error: The Resources was unable to process the data. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
[Entries [657]] Error: The Entries was unable to process the data. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on Resources returned error code 0xC02090F5.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on Entries returned error code 0xC02090F5.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on Assignments returned error code 0xC02090F5.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
[Projects [711]] Error: The error "Column data type 66203200 is not supported by the PipelineBuffer class." occurred while processing "Projects.Outputs[ADO NET Source Output].Columns[project_id]".
[Projects [711]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "Projects" failed because error code 0x80131600 occurred, and the error row disposition on "Projects.Outputs[ADO NET Source Output].Columns[project_id]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
[Projects [711]] Error: The Projects was unable to process the data. Pipeline component has returned HRESULT error code 0xC0209029 from a method call.
[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on Projects returned error code 0xC02090F5.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
```

The odd things is, only some of the data sources in the Data Flow are having issues (3/6).

Here is a list of what I have changed/tired:
- I rebuilt the entire solution using VS 2017 (this worked for ~1 week)
- I tested the ODBC driver(s) (32/64). Both successful.
- I upgraded the project when opening for the first time.
- I recreated the source connection.
- I deleted and recreated the data flow. 
- I deleted and recreated each data source. (Preview of data is successful)
- I updated VS to most current patching.

Nothing has worked! Any input would help.

Comment: What release of VS 2017? What version of SSDT-BI tools?

Comment: Does the package still run if you run it in VS Shell 2010? What prompted the upgrade of VS? And can you tell us more about what happened here: `- I rebuilt the entire solution using VS 2017 (this worked for ~1 week)`?

Comment: Visual Studio Professional 2017 Version 15.8.2

Comment: SSDT SSIS Designer 14.0.3002.105

Comment: The upgrade was due to the need for other developers on the same server having the full version.

Comment: I recreated the package from scratch when I couldn't figure out why I had issues. I searched user forums for days trying to figure it out. Nothing. When I rebuilt, it worked for a while (manually run). Then a couple of days ago, it stopped working. No changes to the package or VS at all.

Comment: We no longer have VS 2010 shell on our machines. It was an enterprise forced upgrade.

Comment: SSDT version 15.1.61808.07020